# Return different values each time from jMockit expectation

Tags: junit, mocking, jmockit

I have a unit test where I am mocking `java.net.URI` class. Further, I am creating a jMockit `NonStrictExpectation` where I am expecting invocation of `URI.getPath()` and returning a particular string.

The code being tested invokes `URI.getPath()` twice, where I need to send a different string each time.

Here is my actual method under test:

```
public void validateResource() {
    // some code
    URI uri = new URI(link1.getHref());
    String path1 = uri.getPath();
    // some more code
    uri = new URI(link2.getHref());
    String path2 = uri.getPath();
}
```

Here is the unit test code:

```
@Mocked URI uri;

@Test
public void testValidateResource() {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {
        {
            // for the first invocation
            uri.getPath(); returns("/resourceGroup/1");

            // for the second invocation [was hoping this would work]
            uri.getPath(); returns("/resource/2");
        }
    };
    myObject.validateResource();
}
```

Now, I want `"/resource/2"` to be returned from my expectation when the `URI.getPath()` is called second time. But it always hits the first expectation and returns `"/recourceGroup/1"`. This is my problem.

How do I make it happen? I can't really use `StrictExpectations` due to a number of reasons, and will have to stick with `NonStrictExpectations`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Seems like you just need to list `uri.getPath()` once, and use the varargs version of `returns`...something like this:

```
uri.getPath(); returns("/resourceGroup/1", "/resourceGroup/2");
```

This is according to the [documentation](https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#results), anyway...I have not tested it myself.

> Multiple consecutive values to return can be recorded for an expectation, by calling the returns(v1, v2, ...) method. Alternatively, the same can be achieved by assigning the **result** field with a list or array containing the consecutive values.